# Differences between address-of and ref operators

Tags: f#, struct, operators, byref

In my code I'm passing around some structures by reference, declaring them mutable and using the `&` symbol. The problem is that in some place the fields are corrupted (happens only in release mode) and I don't know absolutely why.

I have found a fix, using ref keyword instead of the address-of operator. I understand that you can interchange them freely (in case of instance member parameters) but why did it fix my issue?

Here's a small code sample illustrating this:

```
[<Struct>]
type MyStruct =
    val mutable private i : int
    val mutable private f : float
    new (a, b) = { i = a; f = b }
    member t.I = t.i
    member t.F = t.f

type Printer () =
    member t.Print(data : MyStruct byref) = printfn "%d %f" data.I data.F

let bar (p : Printer) =
    let mutable x = new MyStruct(2, 8.0)
    p.Print(&x)

let foo (p : Printer) =
    let mutable y = new MyStruct(2, 8.0)
    p.Print(ref y) // What is exactly the difference, under the hood?

let main () =
    foo (new Printer())
    bar (new Printer())
do main ()
```

Passing structures with byref seems useful only for interop scenarios or if you want to mutate structure's fields. This is not my case however. Should I consider passing structure types by value instead (about 20 bytes or so)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about F#, so unfortunately have no answer to give you. But I think one way to avoid the problem would be not to use the evil that is mutable structs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `ref` in your example may not be exactly what you wanted to write:

```
let modify (data:int byref) = data <- 10

let foo() = 
  let mutable n = 15 // Note: Compiles without 'mutable'
  modify (ref n)
  printfn "%d" n // Prints '10'!!
```

You probably wanted something like this:

```
let foo() = 
  let n = ref 15
  modify n
  printfn "%d" (!n) // Prints '15'
```

So, what is the difference? `ref` is a function that takes a value and creates a heap allocated reference cell. In the second example, the type of `n` is `ref<int>`, which is the reference cell. F# allows you to pass reference cells as arguments to `byref` parameters - in which case, it creates a pointer to a field of the heap-allocated (reference cell) object.

In the second example, we create reference cell, pass a pointer to the reference cell to the `modify` function and then use the `!<ref>` syntax to get value from the reference cell. In the first example, we create a new reference cell when calling the `modify` function (and the value of `n` is copied from the stack to the heap allocated cell). The cell is not used after the call (and the value of `n` stays 15)

On the other hand, a `mutable` variable is simply stored on the stack and can be mutated. The main difference is that `ref` is always heap allocated - using `mutable` could be (in principle) a bit faster, because called function taking `byref` directly modifies value on the stack.